# Вызов Redux Action в componentWillReceiveProps обновляет props и из-за этого возникает бесконечный цикл

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

В componentWillReceiveProps(вызывает при передаче родительским компонентом props `to`, который отправляется при переходе на следующего пользователя) нужно отправлять запрос к Redux, который возвращает данные в виде props.
Из-за того что в componentWillReceiveProps вызывается Redux Action происходит бесконечный цикл повторого вызова этого самого экшена.
Вот код:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
//отправляем действие на загрузку информации в Redux
this.props.getMessage.default(this.props.to);

//загрузка личных данных из api
fetch('/api/getuserinfo/',{
  method: 'POST',
  headers : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
      id:  this.props.to 
    }
  )
})
.then( (result) => {return result.json()})
.then( (data) => {
  this.setState({
    id: this.props.to,
    name : data['name'],
    surname : data['surname'],
    user_foto : data['user_foto']
  });
})
}
```

Comment: Вставьте проверку на наличие нужных полей в props. А лучше - посмотрите станадртный real life пример в репозитории redux, там конкретна эта роблема решена через два разных экшена - на проверну наличия данных и на их реальную загрузку при необходимости

Comment: и да, если у вас redux - то сменой стейта должны заниматься редьюсеры. и никаких fetch прямо в компоненте быть не должно